# Varnish 3.0.2 behind a SSL-Terminator

Tags: varnish

Please do someone know if **varnish 3.0.2** support http redirection to https.

In fact I have a varnish cache server behind a ssl terminator (an aws external loadbalancer on which I set a **http** and a **https** listener).

I would like the varnish when it receives a http request, to redirect in https, and directly send back the response (resquest?) to the loadbalancer, and the loadbalancer will receive the response as a **https** request and forward it the varnih which will then forward it to its own backend.

But it seems like my varnish cache don't redirect back to the loadbalancer but redirect the https request to its backend.

However the backend behind the varnish I don't have a https backend, I get timemout when I issue a http request. 
When the client enter https in the browser it works. The problem is with http request.

Here is my configuration :

In **vcl_recv** :

```
 if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && req.http.host ~ "^(?i)mydomain.com" && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {
        set req.http.x-redir = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
        #return(synth(850, "Moved permanently"));
        error 850 "Moved permanently";
}
```

In **vcl_error** :

```
   if (obj.status == 850) {
    set obj.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
    set obj.status = 302;
    return (deliver);
}
```

Can someone help please. I can't upgrade my varnish version manually at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem,

The security group of the elb was only allowing connection on port **443**, I add the port **80** for the http listener and it works